# Merge sort comparisons?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, mergesort

I don't think the number of comparisons using merge sort is correct in my merge sort 2 class/method that returns the number of comparisons. Merge sort 2 is like merge sort but just returns the amount of comparisons.  Below is my demo, I have an array of 4 integers {2,55,1,45} and when I run the program it returns 8 comparisons. Can anyone verify if this correct or what I am doing wrong?

My demo:

```
    ArrayInts[] myInts2 = new ArrayInts[4];

    myInts2[0] = new ArrayInts(2);
    myInts2[1] = new ArrayInts(55);
    myInts2[2] = new ArrayInts(1);
    myInts2[3] = new ArrayInts(45);

    MergeSort.mergeSort(myInts2, 0, 3);

    System.out.println("Sorted using Merge Sort: ");


    for (int index = 0; index < myInts2.length; index++) {
        System.out.println(myInts2[index]);
    }

    System.out.println("Number of comps using Merge Sort: " + MergeSort2.mergeSort2(myInts2, 0, 3));
    System.out.println(" ");
```

My merge sort 2 class/method:

```
 public class MergeSort2 {
 private static long comp=0;

public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> long mergeSort2(T[] data, int min, int max) {
    T[] temp;
    int index1, left, right;


    //return on list of length one

    if (min == max) {
        return comp;
    }

    //find the length and the midpoint of the list

    int size = max - min + 1;
    int pivot = (min + max) / 2;
    temp = (T[]) (new Comparable[size]);

    mergeSort2(data, min, pivot); //sort left half of list
    mergeSort2(data, pivot + 1, max); //sort right half of list

    //copy sorted data into workspace

    for (index1 = 0; index1 < size; index1++) {
        temp[index1] = data[min + index1];
    }

    //merge the two sorted lists

    left = 0;
    right = pivot - min + 1;
    for (index1 = 0; index1 < size; index1++) {
        comp++;
        if (right <= max - min) {

            if (left <= pivot - min) {

                if (temp[left].compareTo(temp[right]) > 0) {

                    data[index1 + min] = temp[right++];
                } else {
                    data[index1 + min] = temp[left++];
                }
            } else {
                data[index1 + min] = temp[right++];
            }
        } else {
            data[index1 + min] = temp[left++];
        }
    }


    return comp;

    }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

you are getting 8 because you are incrementing each time the merge loop executes whether there is a comparison or not.

if you change

```
for (index1 = 0; index1 < size; index1++) {
    comp++;
    if (right <= max - min) {

        if (left <= pivot - min) {
```

to

```
for (index1 = 0; index1 < size; index1++) {
    if (right <= max - min) {

        if (left <= pivot - min) {
            comp++;
```

you will get the number of comparisions made rather than the number of loop iterations.

[0,1,2,3] should yield 4 comparisons
[3,2,1,0] should yield 4 comparisons
[0,2,1,3] should yield 5 comparisons
[0,4,1,5,2,6,3,7] should yield 16 comparisons

merge sort is an O(nlog2n) worst case algorithm.

you also need to change this bit

```
MergeSort.mergeSort(myInts2, 0, 3);

System.out.println("Sorted using Merge Sort: ");


for (int index = 0; index < myInts2.length; index++) {
    System.out.println(myInts2[index]);
}

System.out.println("Number of comps using Merge Sort: " + MergeSort2.mergeSort2(myInts2, 0, 3));
System.out.println(" ");
```

to

```
int result = MergeSort.mergeSort(myInts2, 0, 3);

System.out.println("Sorted using Merge Sort: ");


for (int index = 0; index < myInts2.length; index++) {
    System.out.println(myInts2[index]);
}

System.out.println("Number of comps using Merge Sort: " + result);
System.out.println(" ");
```

as myInts will be sorted when you output the count so you get the sorted complexity.

to demonstrate the effect of calling sort more than once.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer[] myInts2 = new Integer[4];

    myInts2[0] = new Integer(0);
    myInts2[1] = new Integer(2);
    myInts2[2] = new Integer(1);
    myInts2[3] = new Integer(3);

    System.out.println(new MergeSort2().mergeSort2(myInts2, 0, 3)); // will output 5
    System.out.println(new MergeSort2().mergeSort2(myInts2, 0, 3)); // will output 4
}
```

Calling the sort a second time will use sorted data not unsorted data so you will get
a different result. sorting the array can modify the array so calling the sort multiple
times can get different behaviour.

Comment: What are some example arrays (and their number of comparisons) I should use to test if my class returns the right number of comparisons? Ex. test {0,1,2,3,4,5} and it should return x amount of comparisons.

Comment: Just to double check so I only need one comp++; in my class right?

Comment: you need to have comp++ where you actually make a comparison

Comment: So only one comp++; then right? Where would other comp++; go?

Comment: Ok so I corrected my code based on your answer and when I try to test [0,2,1,3], it returns 4 comparisons instead of 5 comparisons. What i'm  i doing wrong/missing?

Comment: same goes for when I test [0,4,1,5,2,6,3,7] it returns 12 comps instead of 16 comps.

Comment: you are sorting the array twice. the second time when you output the count it is already sorted. I will edit my response.

Comment: no i am not sorting the array twice. I am sorting the array with merge sort (just sort the array using merge sort). Then I am using mergesort2 that only returns the number of comps. using merge sort. I will add my merge sort class to show you.

Comment: Run it EXACTLY how I posted it with everything and test [0,4,1,5,2,6,3,7] it returns 12 comps instead of 16 comps. Something is wrong.

Comment: Run it EXACTLY how I posted it in the main with every class I posted and with comp++; at the right location and then run it. It does not return 16 comps when testing  [0,4,1,5,2,6,3,7] it returns 12 comps.

Answer (score 0):

The number of comparisons you are showing is correct *for the method you have given us*. When an array of length `4` is passed into the method you have given us, the line `comp++;` is called 8 times. Let me explain.

First, `pivot=1`. These lines make two recursive calls:

```
mergeSort2(data, min, pivot); //sort left half of list
mergeSort2(data, pivot + 1, max); //sort right half of list
```

After each of these calls complete their two additional nested recursive calls, they go on to increment `comp` by 2, because the for loop runs a number of iterations equal to `size`. In both of these calls, `size=2`, so after call one, `comp=2`, and after call two, `comp=4`.
Each of these recursive calls in turn make two more recursive calls, however, because in each of these calls, `min==max`, the method returns on `return comp;`, never reaching the line to increment `comp`.

Finally, after the two initial recursive method calls return, the for-loop incrementing `comp` is called four more times, because in the initial call, `size=4`. Thus, `comp = 4 + 4`, which equals 8!

If that was confusing, I'll illustrate my answer with the (`min`, `max`) of each call to `mergesort2()`.

```
/* 1. */ (min=0, max=3) -> size=4, comp = comp + 4;
/* 2. */     (min=0, max=1) -> size=2, comp = comp + 2;
/* 3. */         (min=0, max=0) -> size=0, comp = comp + 0;
/* 4. */         (min=1, max=1) -> size=0, comp = comp + 0;
/* 5. */     (min=2, max=3) -> size=2, comp = comp + 2;
/* 6. */         (min=2, max=2) -> size=0, comp = comp + 0;
/* 7. */         (min=3, max=3) -> size=0; comp = comp + 0;

/* TOTAL. */  comp = 0 + 0 + 2 + 0 + 0 + 2 + 4; comp = 8
```

Hopefully I've made myself clear here!

**edit1:** BevynQ's answer is correct. My answer focuses more on *why your code is returning 8*, while his answer focuses on *why your sort method is incorrectly counting comparisons*.

**edit2:** I copied and pasted your code directly into my editor, and made the one-line change BevynQ added. My code works as intended, and I am not seeing the same results you are. Perhaps something else was accidentally changed?

Comment: Thanks though. If you can help me with another issue Im having check my latest comment to the first answer.

Comment: I copied and pasted your code directly into my editor, and made the one-line change BevynQ added. My code works as intended, and I am not seeing the same results you are. Perhaps something else was accidentally changed?

Comment: Could you post what you have? Because it doesn't work for me and i doubt it works for you too. I checked everything it seems right but the results are wrong.

Comment: Are you testing [0,4,1,5,2,6,3,7]? It returns 12 comps for me. It should instead return 16 comps.

Comment: Yes I have tested [0,4,1,5,2,6,3,7]. I see a return of 16 comparisons. [Here is the code I have.](http://pastebin.com/x6JTgKGD) The only difference is that, because you did not provide the implementation of `ArrayInts`, I simply used Integer. However, as long as `ArrayInts.compareTo()` is implemented properly, this should have no effect on the number of comparisons.

Comment: I will post my ArrayInts class to see if that helps you.

Comment: I have included your `ArrayInts` class, yet still receive the same result: 16 comparisons. Copy and paste my sort method into yours. There must be an error within that method.

Comment: Just caught what BevynQ pointed out! I didn't notice the sly second-sorting call in the output string. I'm glad you got it sorted out!

Comment: Run it EXACTLY how I posted it in the main with every class I posted and with comp++; at the right location and then run it. It does not return 16 comps when testing [0,4,1,5,2,6,3,7] it returns 12 comps.

Comment: edit: I see your edit now. Can you give us the source code of mergeSort and mergeSort2?

Comment: Already posted the source code of mergeSort and mergeSort2. It's updated now.